# Code analysis warning C26481 and std::map with bool array

Tags: visual-c++, code-analysis

I have this definition for an `std::map`:

```
using AssignedStudyPoints = map<CString, bool[kMaxStudyPointCount]>;
```

I have an instance of this as a member variable in one of my classes:

```
AssignedStudyPoints m_mapStudentAssignedStudyPoints;
```

And the constant `kMaxStudyPointCount` is defined as:

```
constexpr int kMaxStudyPointCount = 52;
```

---

Up until now I have been accessing information in this map like this:

```
m_mapStudentAssignedStudyPoints[strStudent][iLastCounsel] = false;
m_mapStudentAssignedStudyPoints[strStudent][iNextCounsel] = true;
if (iNextCounsel == CChristianLifeMinistryDefines::kNoStudyPoint)
    m_mapStudentAssignedStudyPoints[strStudent][iLastCounsel] = true;
```

Code analysis is saying:

> Warning [C26481](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/c26481?view=msvc-160): Don't use pointer arithmetic. Use `span` instead (bounds.1).

So we are back to using a `span`.

---

Now, I can change it like this and use `gsl::at`:

```
gsl::at(m_mapStudentAssignedStudyPoints[strStudent], iLastCounsel) = false;
```

That compiles with no warnings and seems simplest to me. Or, must I use a `gsl::span` instead? Why would it be better?

Comment: If you make your `bool[]` into a `std::vector<bool>` you can just use the STL `at()` function, and no need for gsl.

Comment: @AdrianMole Thanks for the suggestion. If I change it to: `using AssignedStudyPoints = map<CString, std::vector<bool>>;` how do we init the vector to `kMaxStudyPointCount`?

Comment: Oops. Should've been `std::array<bool, kMaxStudyPointCount>`, maybe? And make that a `size_t`, not an `int`.

Comment: @AdrianMole It works! Awesome. :)